# What types of regression models are used identify which features are most important in relation to Y?

Tags: regression

My goal is to plot a regression model to see which of the (X1 ... XN) columns have the most impact on the Response Variable, Y. And to plot this

My question is what what regression models should I look into?

Case if there is a linearity?

Case if there is not linearity?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take "most impact" to mean those variables which result in the largest change in the outcome.  Most of the generalized linear models are capable of doing this.  You would first need to scale the predictors so that they all have the same units.  This can be done by z-standardizing your continuous variables.  Then, fit your model and extract the coefficients.  The coefficient estimate tells you the expected change in the outcome per a one unit change in your predictor.

In the non-linear case, you can use a GAM or a spline.

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying. Your assumption is correct. by "most impact" I mean which induces the largest change in the response per unit change in the independent variable

Comment: If say 3 variables are linear and 2 are non linear. Would I still be able to order them from "most impactful" from 1-5 even though for some non linear models were implemented?